# Remove E9 and decimal from the column in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have many records whose data has  been uploaded incorrectly while uploading excel in a `oracle` table. The results of some are as below

**8.632233817E9, 
8.63227224E9, 
8.819243113E9**

So now what I want is I want to remove `E9` which is in the last of every value and also the decimal.

**Note** I don't want to remove the `9` if it comes in the middle of any number.

its query is

`select STORE_SITENAME_LANDL_2, RRSOC_ID from TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO;`

where `RRSOC_ID` is my primary key value

Comment: Are you sure? 8.819243113E9 is usually simply a way of writing 8.819243113 * 10^9, i.e. 8819243113.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: yes, because it got copied while uploading from excel

Comment: So what value shall 8.819243113E9 get converted to? What data type is your column?

Comment: i dont want to convert it, i want it to delete the last two values if it contains `E`.  and also remove the decimal. datatype is NVARCHAR2(155)

Comment: Why do you have a text column for numeric values? You shouldn't. Maybe all this wouldn't have happened with a numeric data type (e.g. `NUMBER(10)`), because as mentioned 8.819243113E9 *is* 8819243113.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to remove `E9` from such data, you should simply use

```
select 
  replace(STORE_SITENAME_LANDL_2, 'E9'),
  replace(RRSOC_ID, 'E9'),
  replace(STORE_CODE, 'E9')
from 
  TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO;
```

But do you really wish exactly what you said? Maybe

```
select 
  to_number(STORE_SITENAME_LANDL_2, '9.999999999999999EEEE'),
  to_number(RRSOC_ID, '9.999999999999999EEEE'),
  to_number(STORE_CODE, '9.999999999999999EEEE')
from 
  TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO;
```

is what you really required?

Answer (score 0):

As `8.819243113E9` is just another way of writing for `8819243113` as already mentioned in the comment to your request, simply convert your string to number:

```
update mytable
set col = to_number(col, '9.9999999999999999999EEEE')
WHERE col LIKE '_.%E%';
```

This also takes care of values like `8.8192E9` which is `8819200000` (and not `88192`, which you would get with your approach where you'd just remove 9E and the decimal separator).

But as already mentioned, you shouldn't store numbers in a text column to start with. Make this a numeric column and such mistakes cannot occur.

Comment: getting error as `SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"` this is the query `UPDATE TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO set STORE_SITENAME_LANDL_2 = select to_number(STORE_SITENAME_LANDL_2, '9.9999999999999999999EEEE');`

Comment: Oops, a typo. `select` doesn't belong of course. I've updated my answer.

Comment: now getting error as `SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"`

Comment: Then there are numbers that are not in scientific format in that column. Add a `WHERE`clause: `WHERE col LIKE '_.%E%'`.

Comment: i know it, but for future readers it would be great I think so.. if u dont want i will update it with my answer :)

Comment: For future readers the answer is **"Don't use text columns for numeric values"**. It's the same answer for you. I'm showing a workaround, but it's nothing more than that.